# Nativescript tests don't run when following tutorial instructions with NS 5

Tags: angular, unit-testing, nativescript

Following the instructions for the NativeScript Angular tutorial, I do the following:

(`tns --version` reports `5.0.0`)

`` tns create HelloWorld --template tns-template-blank-ng
cd HelloWorld
tns run ios --emulator
// The HelloWorld app runs correctly
tns test init
// Select Jasmine
tns test ios --emulator
// Get the error:
NativeScript / 10.3.1 (10.3.1; iPhone): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.009 secs / 0 secs)
// Also get the warning:
CONSOLE ERROR DEPRECATION: Setting specFilter directly on Env is deprecated, please use the specFilter option in `configure` ``

If I rename the generated `example.js` to `example.spec.js` I get the same error. If I move the `tests` folder into the `apps` folder I get the same error.

I can't figure out how to run unit tests with NS 5.